# What download do I use to add the Russian Cyrullic characters to my Windows 10 QWERTY keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language-bar

I need to download the appropriate Cyrrilic (Russian language) characters on my new keyboard.  I use Windows 10. My keyboard is US American English
QWERTY with the Russian characters set lower Right which include:
English Q as Russian short Ee
"    A as    "          F
"    Z as    "          Ya

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, so I can't check, but there is be an option somewhere in the Windows settings to add a keyboard layout. You shouldn't need to download anything